# JPA 1.2 createQuery Where Clause Criteria

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, jpa-2.0

Hi there I am complete newbie to JPA.
I am trying to select a particular set of records using one column as the criteria.
My entity code was auto generated based on the table structure as follows:

```
create table TEST.COMPUTERS(
       "COLUMN1" VARCHAR2(6) not null,
       "COLUMN2" VARCHAR2(10) not null,
       "COLUMN3" VARCHAR2(5) not null,
       "COLUMN4" VARCHAR2(8) not null,
       "COLUMN5" VARCHAR2(48),
        constraint "PK" primary key ("COLUMN1","COLUMN2")
    );
```

Contructor Code for Entiry Class:

```
@Table(name = "COMPUTERS", schema = "TEST") 
public class Computers implements java.io.Serializable {


 /** full constructor */
        public Computers(ComputersId id, String column3, String column4,
                String column5) {
            this.id = id;
            this.column3 = column3;
            this.column4 = column4;
            this.column5 = column5;
        }

          @EmbeddedId
          public ComputersId getId() {
            return this.id;
       }

      public void setId(ComputersId id) {
        this.id = id;
      }
        // and then ....getter and setter methods for Column 3-5
```

I then do the following:

```
Query query  =   EntityManagerHelper.getEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT s from Computers s where s.column1 = :column1").setParameter("column1", "SONY LAPTOPS");
```

Upon running the above I get the following error:

```
An error occurred while parsing the query filter "SELECT s from Computers where s.column1 = :column1". Error message: No field named "column1" in class "class Computers".
```

Any pointers on this please ? Many thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the Column1 is part of the embededId you have to go through the id field:

```
Query query  =   EntityManagerHelper.getEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT s from Computers s where s.id.column1 = :column1").setParameter("column1", "SONY LAPTOPS");
```

PS: Your columns seem to have rather poorly chosen names..? Perhaps you should give them some more descriptive names?

Comment: Thanks a  million!! Barsju  solved the problem, and yes I will be recreating the table using proper column names....